# Replacing column data with Pandas .replace not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to turn [data from a .csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b_g03kXxpOPUzZeuJ3P03wGxP2JBkZuP/view?usp=sharing) into a Pandas df:

```
df = pd.read_csv('congress1.csv', delimiter = ';', names = ['Name', 'Years', 'Position', 'Party', 'State', 'Congress'], header = 0)
```

I want to replace the data in column "Congress" - "1(1789-1790)" - with a single date - "1789":

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].replace('1(1789-1790)', '1789')
```

However, doing so does not change any of my data. If I, say, include inplace=True

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].replace('1(1789-1790)', '1789', inplace=True)
```

... my data in that column of course becomes null. Yet I can't seem to replace this string with anything meaningful.

Comment: Please look at the @Willem's answer , However you dont need  `inplace=true` as you are assigning back it to the `df['Congress']`  columns so it will be inplaced!  if you are looking for a single instance then its done in case you are looking this to be replaced across `Congress` for all dates then you need a regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you should use the `.str` part to "interpret" the column as strings; and
2. you need to *escape* the brackets.

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].str.replace(r'1\(1789-1790\)', '1789')
```

So we replace the string part with `1789`.